# How can I create an executable from LLVM ir?

Tags: windows, assembly, llvm, nasm, llvm-ir

I am currently using [llc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) to convert a `.ll` file to a `.s` using the commandline. Then I want to take this file and then use [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/index.php) to create an executable from it. While the first step seems to work fine, I can't get the second step to work.

---

the original file is called `code.ll` and contains the following code:

```
define i32 @main() {
    ret i32 0
}
```

now I use the cmd to build the `.s` file by typing:

> llc code.ll

this works fine and creates a `code.s` file containing the following code:

```
    .def     @feat.00;
    .scl    3;
    .type   0;
    .endef
    .globl  @feat.00
@feat.00 = 1
    .def     _main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .align  16, 0x90
_main:                                  # @main
# BB#0:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    ret
```

Now I want to create an executable using this code, about which the [llc doc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) tells me this:

> The assembly language output can then be passed through a native assembler and linker to generate a native executable.

So I use [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/index.php)  (which should do what I want as far as I understand) by typing:

> nasm code.s

which produces the following list of errors:

```
code.s:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
code.s:1: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:2: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
code.s:2: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:3: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
code.s:3: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:4: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
code.s:5: error: attempt to define a local label before any non-local labels
code.s:5: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:6: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:7: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:8: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:9: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:12: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:13: error: parser: instruction expected
code.s:14: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::1: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::2: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::3: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::4: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::5: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::8: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::9: error: parser: instruction expected
BB#0::10: error: parser: instruction expected
```

---

As my experience concerning LLVM  or assembler is close to zero I were unable to solve this myself.

In case I have left out something important just tell me and I will edit my answer as fast as possible.

Comment: The generated code is in AT&T syntax and NASM won't understand it. You'd have to use GNU assembler (`as`) to assemble that `.s` file or any assembler capable of understanding AT&T syntax.

Comment: @Michael Petch Ok, while I can't test it atm it definitely sounds like this is is what I needed. Would you mind to write a answer so I can accept it. In case you don't have the time for it I will just write a self answer in a few days, which would pretty much just reiterate your answer with a short explaination of what AT&T syntax is and what syntax is is used by NASM. Thanks

Comment: Please be my guest and self answer when you think you have resolved it.

Comment: LLVM has it's own assembler you should be able to use or better yet `llc` can generate an object file directly without having to invoke a "native assembler" at all.You'd just need to use a native linker on the object file to create a native executable.

Comment: @MichaelPetch - To produce intel assembly syntax use `llc -x86-asm-syntax=intel filename.ll` ***but*** it is still not 100% `nasm` compatible. I just use `clang` at that point to compile/link to executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of [@Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985953/how-can-i-create-an-executable-from-llvm-ir?noredirect=1#comment78933509_45985953) and [@Ross Ridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985953/how-can-i-create-an-executable-from-llvm-ir?noredirect=1#comment78935354_45985953) I finally understood why this does not work and found a working alternative.

---

## The cause of the problem

There are different kinds of assembler language, which vary in syntax and are not directly compatible. As [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/index.php) is expecting another assembly language than [llc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) is producing, it obviously does not work, which explains the long list of errors.

## How to do it instead

Considering that [llc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) has AT&T assembler as output, which was created for the [GNU toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_toolchain), the most obvious step would be to use [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) to create the executable after building the `code.s` file with [llc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html).

To install [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) I downloaded [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), installed it and called

> mingw-get install gcc

now I can access [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) which can be used to create `code.exe` by calling

> gcc code.s -o code.exe

`gcc [filename] -o [name of the created executable]`

---

As this solution is probably more complicated than it needs to be I would be glad to see some alternatives/ improvements.

Comment: If you have `llvm` don't you already have `clang`? That would save you adding YATC (yet another tool chain).

Comment: Frank is right.  `clang` already has an assembler built-in, or can use `as` from binutils.  You don't need gcc to build `.s` files if you already have `clang`.

Comment: @Frank C. As far as I know, I do not have clang/I would need to download it. But as long as my way of doing I this way works I do not want to spend a rather large amount of time learning how to do it another way, even if my way is more complicated